# Find out wep key from embeded client

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, embedded, wep

im kinda stuck here i have an embedded system i was given from a friend that connects to a wifi network to configure it unfortunately he cant remember the WEP key that was used to connect it. is there a way to recover the key from the client (WITHOUT AP) and there is no reset switch on it either. i have some basic linux knowledge so i could use something like Kali to do this.

thanks
Sam

Comment: Difficult to answer without any details, like exact model of the embedded system, whether it has a serial console or not, whether it has LAN or not, ... While WEP is crackable e.g. with `aircrack-ng` (WITH an AP so you can sniff traffic), there are very likely easier ways to get in.

Comment: hi its a VIX TP5000 it runs some version of linux on powerPC arch there is no Ethernet and there is something that looks like serial but with 6v on one pin and 0 on another and the last is common to system ground. I have though about using aircrack but id need to find a willing host to let me have a go with there system

Answer (score 0):

Partial answer:

[This](http://www.hklpacific.com.au/erg/TICKET%20PROCESSOR%20-%20TP5000.html) page says the VIX TP5000 ticket processer has an [RS422](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RS-422) interface option, which uses a 6V differential signal. So first thing I'd do is to get an RS422 USB dongle for 20 EUR or so, and have a look.

Next thing I'd do is to put it in a room with some access point with random SSID, and sniff traffic on a third computer with `airomon` from `aircrack-ng` and/or with `wireshark` once you found a channel, to see if that gives any clues.

**Edit**

As it scans for an AP with SSID `ERG`, do the following:

- Use `hostapd` to set up an unencrypted AP, see if it connects (i.e., associates and authenticates, use `hostapd_cli`). If yes, you have won.
- Otherwise, set up a WEP-encrypted AP, sniff traffic and see if you can't use this to crack the WEP password.

Once it connects, run `wireshark` on the AP network interface. If you see a DHCP request, run a DHCP server. If you don't see any, maybe it already has a static IP address. Try a broadcast ping (`ping -b -I 255.255.255.255`), if necessary scan the whole IPv4 address range with ping.

Comment: thanks for that ordering one later today and the 'airomon' says its probing for a WiFi network called ERG. I  have run 'airbase-ng' and im being told its shared authentication with 140 bytes key stream. when the RS422 interface arrives ill see what that uncovers.

Comment: So setup an AP with SSID `ERG`, and see what happens ...

Comment: tried that on a old ap i had laying around it didn't seem to connect to it and it didn't get an ip address either. 'airbase-ng' allows it to connect but still the device does not get an ip if i bridge the 'wlan0' interface to 'eth0' interface. (other devices get IP's from DHCP with the airbase-ng method)